# Reactive Spring - Request body is missing -

Tags: spring-webflux, openapi-generator

I have a Reactive Rest Controller that makes a POST call along with Flux<> Request Body.
I want to do sequential steps in this Post call

1. Validate Request Body input
2. Delete all rows based on one field inside Request Body.
3. Save all data from this Flux Request Body
4. Return all updated saved data from Flux to Controller

```
Sample Code
    public Mono<Boolean> update(Flux<RequestBody> body, Long id) {.   
         return body.   
              .flatMap(d -> this.repo.deleteCriteria(id, d.getValue);    
              .thenMany(body)       
              .flatMap(m-> {mapper to convert from DTO to Entity});      
              .flatMap(s -> this.repo.save(s.name, s.data)       
              .then(c -> this.repo.findById(id).count)     
              .then(n-> n.intValue() > 0 ? Mono.just(true) : Mono.just(false));    
   

    }.   

Controller code -
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED).  
    @PostMapping("/abc").   
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<Void> update(Long id, Flux<Body> body) {    
        Mono<Boolean> onSuccess = this.service.update(id, body);    
            onSuccess    
            .log()
            .flatMap(b -> b ? Mono.just(new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.CREATED) :   
          Mono.just(new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR));      
    }
```

I see in Logs that Delete statement getting executed n times. Ideally I wanted it only one time to run but I only know flatMap().
But after delete statement I see below error in logs.
"Error - 400 Bad Request - Request body is missing ....."

FYI - Before when I only had a delete statement and I was not fetching value from Flux Request Body everything was working fine.

Please let me know if there is a way to

1. read values from Request Body and do validations.
2. perform multiple operations on this Request body like Delete, save and find by reading some values from the RequestBody.
   Any help appreciated :)